# DynamicInvoke in an Async task running in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, reflection, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I have a generic method that initializes synchronization thread for objects of type T (WinRT). Within this synchronization thread, I call a delegate handler whenever an object is synchronized, so the code looks something like this:

```
foreach (var e in updatedEntities)
{
    if (mHandlers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        mHandlers[typeof(T)].DynamicInvoke(e);
    }
}
firstUpdate[typeof(T)] = true;
```

Now for my app to work correctly, I need to wait for all the firstUpdate values to be true (they're initialized as false by default).

My problem is that even though the handlers are in format:

```
public void EntityUpdated(SyncedDatatypes.MyEntityType entity)
```

The DynamicInvoke appears to run in a separate thread as firstUpdate is set to true before the delegate behind DynamicInvoke is completed.

So as it is not a task nor an async method, I am really confused by this behavior. How can I make sure that all my handlers have been called once? i.e. how do I "await" the DynamicInvoke?

Comment: `DynamicInvoke` does not run on a separate thread. There is probably some other kind of race condition in your code, or you are possibly using an `async void EntityUpdated`.

Comment: It was asynchronous before, I changed it to synchronous without any change in the behavior. I've looked over it so many time it's hard to imagine what could be causing this. One thing I can think of is that this is a part of a long running task. An in order to start that, I didn't use Task.Run, but Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { ... }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

Comment: Well, you know that `StartNew` doesn't understand `async`, right? It will return "early".

Comment: Yeah, I know. I thought this applied to stuff like await, but apparently DynamicInvoke also has a similar effect in this case. Any way around it, though? Because I kind-of want to maximize the chances of my task running in a separate thread and the only way I could see of doing that is by using TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.

Comment: `Task.Run` will run in a separate thread. All that `LongRunning` does is inform the thread pool scheduler that the task is long-running. You should just use `Task.Run`.

Comment: Alright. Thank you, Stephen.

Comment: Even after the change though, the problem persists. I might've been going at it completely wrong and there's something else profoundly wrong with my code.

Comment: The very simple solution is to define a interface (for example name it `ITaskToDo`) with just one method call it `DoIT()` (or anything you fancy) and pass it to be executed instead of the delegate. You can implement it in the objects "entities" that need updating. If you need to do it dynamically, than you can add a second method to the interface - let's say `bool DoINeedToBeUpdated()` and determine this way if you have to update or not. And any parameters can already be inside the object(s) implementing `ITaskToDo` in `updatedEntities` that you have.